# Convergence Related to Law of Large Numbers

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, random-variables, law-of-large-numbers

$Z_1, Z_2, Z_3,...$ are independent and identically distributed R>V.s s.t. $E(Z)_i^- < \infty$ and $E(Z)_i^+ = \infty$. Prove that $$\frac {Z_1+Z_2+Z_3+...+Z_n} n \to \infty$$ almost surely.

What does $E(Z)_i^+$ $E(Z)_i^-$ mean? i dont understand the +,- sign. But If E(Z)=$\infty$, then according to law of large numbers, the average of $\sum Zi$ is of course $\infty$. Or do i need to use other theorems to prove this?

Comment: $E(Z)_i^- = -\mathbb E[\min(Z_i,0)]$, $E(Z)_i^+ = \mathbb E[\max(Z_i,0)]$

Comment: got it, may i also ask why $P(|Zn-Z|>\epsilon^p) \le \frac 1 {\epsilon^p} E|Zn-Z|^p$? for all positive epsilons

Comment: This is not true. If l.h.s. is $P(|Z_n-Z|>\epsilon)$ and $p>1$, then it is Markov inequality.

Comment: oh makes sense only if i have |zn-Z| to the pth power then it is true, thanks again!

Comment: is that first statement equivalent to max[E(Zi), o] btw? which would mean $E(Zi)=\infty$?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood you correctly, but if expectation of left tail if finite and the expectation of right tail is infinite than the expected value of r.v. is infinite too. Note that LLN is applicable to a sequence with finite expectations.

Answer (score 1):

The sequence $\{Z_n^{+}\}$ and $\{Z_n^{-}\}$ are also i.i.d..   Suppose we prove that $\frac {Z_1^{+}+...+Z_n^{+}} n \to \infty$ almost surely. Then we can apply Strong Law to $\{Z_n^{-}\}$ and use $Z_n=Z_n^{+}-Z_n^{-}$ to complete the proof. Fix a positive integer $N$ and let $Y_n =\min (Z_n^{+},N)$. Then $\{Y_n\}$ is i.i.d. and Strong Law gives $\frac {Y_1+Y_2+...+Y_n} n \to EY_1$ almost surely. Since $Y_n \leq Z_N^{+}$ this gives $\liminf  \frac {Z_1^{+}+Z_2^{+}+...+Z_n^{+}} n \geq EY_1=E\min (Z_1^{+},N)$. This is true for each $N$. Now note that (by Monotone Convergence Theorem) $E\min (Z_1^{+},N) \to EZ_1^{+}=\infty$. This proves that $\frac {Z_1^{+}+...+Z_n^{+}} n \to \infty$ almost surely.

Comment: srorry i did some research and $E(Zi)^-$ should be integrating from $-\infty$ to 0? and $\infty$ to 0 for $E(Zi)^+$

Comment: or it should be max and min? thanks

Comment: I really don't understand your comments. The definitions of $X^{+}$ and $X^{-}$ are  $X^{+}=\max \{X,0\}$ and $X^{-}=-\min \{X,0\}$.